# ERROR: subnets is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

Tags: yaml, ansible, amazon-vpc

I am new to Ansible and would appreciate some help with my playbook. I would like to create a VPC in AWS with 2 subnets. Here is the error I am getting:

```
[root@aws]# ansible-playbook --syntax-check vpc_pub_pri.yml
playbook: vpc_pub_pri.yml
ERROR: subnets is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
```

Any help would be great~ Cheers~

```
---
- name: Provision a VPC with public/private subnets and an IGW
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Create 2 subnets
    module: ec2_vpc
    region: us-west-2
    cidr_block: 192.168.0.0/23
    resource_tags: { "Name":"vpc" }
    subnets:
      - cidr: 192.168.0.0/24
        az: us-west-2a
        resource_tags: { "Name":"public" }
      - cidr: 192.168.1.0/24
        az: us-west-2c
        resource_tags: { "Name":"private" }
    internet_gateway: True
    route_tables:
      - subnets:
          - 192.168.0.0/24
          - 192.168.1.0/24
        routes:
          - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
            gw: igw
    register: vpc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the rest of the parameters will be ok, but the main problem here is the indention. subnet etc are parameters of the `ec2_vpc` module. Also, I have never seen the `module:` notation, might be ok or not. But this should work:

```
---
- name: Provision a VPC with public/private subnets and an IGW
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Create 2 subnets
    ec2_vpc: 
      region: us-west-2
      cidr_block: 192.168.0.0/23
      resource_tags: { "Name":"vpc" }
      subnets:
        - cidr: 192.168.0.0/24
          az: us-west-2a
          resource_tags: { "Name":"public" }
        - cidr: 192.168.1.0/24
          az: us-west-2c
          resource_tags: { "Name":"private" }
      internet_gateway: True
      route_tables:
        - subnets:
            - 192.168.0.0/24
            - 192.168.1.0/24
          routes:
            - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
              gw: igw
    register: vpc
```

Comment: Ok that was quick. Thanks a ton Udondan, that seems to do the trick~ I had the "module:" notation in my other script and it seems to work. I was looking for some sort of standard notation but I guess I'm just not used to the various types. Thanks again for the help~